# return list by dataframe linear interpolation

Tags: dataframe, interpolation

I have a dataframe that has, let's say 5 entries.

|  | moment | stress | strain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.12 | 13 | 0.11 |
| 1 | 0.23 | 14 | 0.12 |
| 2 | 0.56 | 15 | 0.56 |

I would like to get a 1D float list in the order of [moment, stress, strain], based on the linear interpolation of strain = 0.45

I have read a couple of threads talking about the interpolate() method from pandas. But it is used when you have Nan entry and you fill in the number.

How do I accomplish a similar task with my case?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to add new row to your dataframe with NaN values and sort it:

```py
df = df.append(
    {"moment": np.nan, "stress": np.nan, "strain": 0.45}, ignore_index=True
)
df = df.sort_values(by="strain").set_index("strain")
df = df.interpolate(method="index")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        moment  stress
strain                
0.11    0.1200   13.00
0.12    0.2300   14.00
0.45    0.4775   14.75
0.56    0.5600   15.00
```

---

To get the values back:

```
df = df.reset_index()
print(
    df.loc[df.strain == 0.45, ["moment", "stress", "strain"]]
    .to_numpy()
    .tolist()[0]
)
```

Prints:

```
[0.47750000000000004, 14.75, 0.45]
```